# Populating a table column-wise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am implementing a HTML table in my Rails application. Currently, I have in my **view**:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <% @electives.each do |elective| %>
        <th><%= elective.name %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`Elective` and `Course` are models in my application. I have created a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between them, thereby creating a `courses_electives` table.

At present, my webpage looks like:

[image: Screenshot of webpage]

What I want to do next is display all the courses related to each elective under the elective name.

I think I can achieve this using:

```
<% @electives.each do |elective| %>
  <% elective.courses.each do |course| %>
    <%= course.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem I am facing with this approach is that it doesn't allow me to build my table vertically. I can create new `<td>` elements inside the above loops, but that will render data horizontally. That is, courses which belong to Software Engineering Elective A will end up being `<td>` entries in Software Engineering Elective B and so on.

What I want is:

[image: Screenshot of image]

How can I achieve this? Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sliim's suggestion is good. But what you're battling here is the limitations of html concepts that are over 30 years old. We now have grid and flexbox, which are much better ways to arrange elements on the page than tables. So how would this look in `modern` html? (well, I'll use haml b/c it's easier to see the structure, and b/c I'm lazy and haml rocks)

```
#electives
  - @electives.each do |elective|
    .elective
      .name= elective.name
      - elective.courses.each do |course|
        .course= course.name
```

This just gives you a bunch of divs, but with a little css magic we can create the arrangement that you want:

```css
#electives {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}
.elective {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

The `grid-template-columns`  'auto-fit' declaration adjusts to however many columns you may have, whilst setting minimum and maximum widths. It's described [here](https://css-tricks.com/books/greatest-css-tricks/flexible-grids/).

Of course, the flexbox doesn't care that there are different numbers of courses in each elective.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer. I was just wondering, what is the use of Flexbox here, when Grid automatically lays out the data in a vertical fashion? I found that omitting .elective styling doesn't change the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) to flip the columns and the rows.

```
<% @electives.map(&:courses).transpose.each do |row| %>
  <tr>
    <% row.each do |course| %>
      <td>
        <%= course.name %>
      </td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Do be careful with `nil`-s here, because I assume your electives might not have exactly the same amount of courses.